# Incorrect currentTime with videojs when streaming HLS

Tags: rtmp, video.js, http-live-streaming, duration

I'm streaming both RTMP and HLS(for IOS and android), with RTMP video.js display correct currentTime. According to me currentTime should be when the stream started, not when the client started to view the stream. But when I go with the HLS-stream currentTime returns when the client started the stream and not when the stream started(same result using any player from android or ios or VLC).

Using ffprobe on my HLS-stream I get the correct values, i.e when the stream started, which makes me believe that I should start looking at the client to find a solution, but I'm far from sure.

So please help me get in the right direction to solve this problem.

I.e is it HLS in nature that doesn't give me correct currentTime, but weird that ffprobe gives me correct answer?

Can't find anything in the video.js code on how to get any other time code.

Is it my server that generates wrong SMTPE timecode for HLS and ffprobe are using other ways to get correct currentTime?

Anyway I'm just curious, I have a workaround for it, by initially counting used fragments I will atleast get in the 5 seconds ballpark, i.e good enough for my case.

Thanks for any help or input.

BR David

Answer (score 0):

RTMP and HLS work in different ways.
RTMP is always streaming, and when you subscribe to the stream, you subscribe to the running stream, so the begin time will be when the stream started.

HLS works differently. When you subscribe to a HLS stream, it creates a stream for you. So the current time will be when the HLS stream was started, which means when you subscribed and the HLS stream was created.